# 404 error tomcat when running a servlet

Tags: tomcat, servlets, http-status-code-404

I wonder if anyone could help me please.I have built a simple servlet but when I run it I get the 404 error.

I didn't use eclipse or netbeans for my servlet just notepad++ and cmd. I have also set up JAVA_HOME and CATALINA_HOME

This is my url : `http://localhost:8080/FirstServlet/myfirstservlet.`

I have been searching for solution for last few hours and it's still not working.
Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: `PrintWriter out = res.getWriter90;` Is that a typo? it should be `PrintWriter out = res.getWriter();`

Comment: Does your code compiles properly?

Comment: @MaVRoSCy thank you for pointing it out. Oddly enough, my code did compile. I fixed the typos( there were more than one) but unfortunately it's still not working :(

Comment: It is `WEB-INF`, not `WEB-INFO`.

Comment: @MaVRoSCy thanks :) I just change the folder's name but still the same :/

Comment: Have you checked in the tomcat log that it's actually deployed your application? You should see a line saying something like 'deploying application /FirstServlet'.

Comment: @SimonCurd Thanks for your reply. I've just checked the log and it has deployed it.

Comment: Just noticed the doGET method is spelt incorrectly, which would mean you're not overriding the doGet(...) method in the parent class, so your logic won't get called. Try correcting that and redeploying.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change in web.xml

By adding attributes to "web-app" tag like:

```
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee
                      http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
  version="3.1"
  metadata-complete="false">
```

if you have already not done it.

Check for enviornment variable

Variable Name:  CLASSPATH 
Variable Value:  /lib/servlet-api.jar

I think your class path is not set.

Or

Dump all the source files in /webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/classes and add the lines in web.xml already present in /webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF.

Hope this helps!!